# Image Recogniser / Find and replace Tool

Tags: image-processing

i have a folder "A" with 3000 images, all are 400px x 400px  and named from 1 to 3000.
Also I have an other folder "B" with the original images, the same of folder "A" in hi-resolution.. All are 2000px x 2000px named with the original names...
I want to find a tool that helps me to recognize images from the folder "A" in low resolution and replace them with the original ones and keeping the name from the folder "A", so from 1 to 3000.

Any suggestion

Comment: Any preference as to language? There is [a free, open library for C++](http://cimg.eu/) that offers image recognition.

Comment: @cantelope, thanks for the hint! i'll give it a read... i'll let you know!

Comment: You can give [KNIME Image Processing](http://knime.imagej.net) a try. No programming skills needed.